# Rethinkdb group sequence by N elements

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a sequence inside a document

`{
    errorTicker: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
}`

I would like to do a group by N elements and get

for N = 3
`{
    errorTicker: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
}`

What would have been ideal solution:

```
r.expr([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).group(function(entry, index){
    return r.expr(index).div(3).coerceTo('string').split('.')(0);
})
```

but group does not accept current index, only the entry being processed...

What magic could I use here to achieve the desired result?

P.S. order of the sequence is important to me i.e. group [1,2,3] is not the same as [1,3,5]

Answer (score 1):

I'm *almost* on the right track, thanks to `.range()` command

Here is the intermediate version i'm working on right now

```
r.expr({tickers: [9,6,3,9,6,7,8,1,2]})
  .do(function (e){
    return r.range(e('tickers').count())
      .map(function(index){
        return [index, e('tickers')(index)]
      })
      .group(function(indexValue){
        return r.expr(indexValue(0)).div(3).coerceTo('string').split('.')(0);
      })
    })
```

The final version that seems to do what I need:

```
r.expr({tickers: [9,6,3,9,6,7,8,1,2]})
  .do(function (e){
    return r.range(e('tickers').count())
      .map(function(index){
        return [index, e('tickers')(index)]
      })
      .group(function(indexValue){
        return r.expr(indexValue(0)).div(3).coerceTo('string').split('.')(0);
      })
      .ungroup()
      .map(function(e){
        return e('reduction').map(function(e){
          return e(1)
        })
      })      
    })
```

Would appreciate any improvements ;)

updated: to get more efficience we can replace 
`r.expr(indexValue(0)).div(3).coerceTo('string').split('.')(0)`

with

`r.expr(index).sub(r.expr(index).mod(3)).div(3);`

P.S. rethinkdb totally rocks! it's the most powerful and intuitive NoSQL database I've ever used :)